# android play store updates and reversion

Tags: android, google-play

thankfully I don't think I have a problem with my app, but the chance of this issue made me want to ask the question on SO.

Scenario: Assuming many folk have automatic updating set against my app (as I do), what would happen if I launched an update that percolated through the market, only to find that I had cocked-up something major and needed time to fix. My first action would be to deactivate the newest version, and activate the next older version.

Question: What would happen on the phone if they have the newer version? Would it automatically update to the older 'live' version?

And yes, I know I should test, test, test so that I never get in this position...;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, downgrade won't work, yet, by unpublishing faulty app you prevent those who did not upgrade yet from facing problems, but those who already upgraded can simply uninstall the app and install it again, thus revering to last stable version. Market will not downgrade installed apps. It only works for updates (comparing versionCodes)

Comment: Figured, but nice to know for sure. Thanks.